# Exchange 2003 Defrag is too slow

Tags: exchange-2003, windows-sbs, defrag

I have a Exchange database that has been cleaned out and a lot of space freed up. I would like to defrag the database using eseutil, but it is taking too long.

I've tried moving the files to my desktop and running them there instead of the server (server is quite old). I don't understand what the bottle neck is. Disk IO, CPU and memory usage are all low.

I've even tried running the defrag from some really large amazon ec2 instances, and no matter what, it seems like it is going to take 12+ hours to defrag my 30 Gig File.

Any suggestions are relcomed

Comment: Try repairing with `eseutil /p` yet? It might be damaged.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a version of Exchange 2003 that will allow you to move to a new database?  It might be easier to move the users to a new database and simply remove the old one.

Unfortunately, Exchange 2003 was a bit pokey when defraging, especially on older hardware.  But rather than defrag it, decommision it instead. (Assuming you can)